# Can i use iframe for a html file?

Tags: html, iframe

Let's say that i have a div with a lot of contents like this:

```
<div id="g_image4" style=""><img src="images/content1.png" alt="" title=""></div>

<div id="g_text4" style="">
<div class="wpmd1">
<div><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Tahoma" class="ws11"> Cele mai recente </font></div>
<div><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Tahoma" class="ws12"><a href="anime/Basilisk/3.html"  
target="_self" class="style1">Basilisk Ep. 3</a></font></div>
<div><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Tahoma" class="ws12"><a 
href="anime/NarutoShippuden/317.html"  target="_self" class="style1">Naruto Shippuden   
Ep. 317</a></font></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is a div content wich i've insert it in many pages,and i need to update it daily.But it's difficult to edit all pages daily to change names or path or somethings else from this div.
So i was though there is another way,a simple one like iframe.But i dont know if it works with html files from the same folder.And if it doesnt work,then is there any other way to do this without editing like 500 pages daily?

Comment: You can use an iframe for any file you can get a valid URL to. What happened when you tried?

Comment: Well i didn't tried already because i'm not sure it will work.I wanna know if there is anyway to do it,and how.And as i said i  need something wich work with a path like "index.html" not a url because it's a file from my parent folder.

Comment: You can build a file just for that and use php includes

Comment: and the div will appear in page as a iframe? or how it works?

Comment: No it will not place it as an iframe, but it will be placed on the page. The link in the answer will explain more into detail.

Comment: @LebadaPetru it will work just fine. You can refer to a plain path, and the remote client understands to adjust it to be relative to the page that provided it. that being said, if your server does have php, it's a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it using php. Create a php file named something like div.php and put your code in that. Then use the following on each page:

```
<?php include 'div.php'; ?>
```

Using this when you update "div.php" every page you put the php includes on will be updated.

Here is a link to help you [W3schools PHP includes](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Comment: Let me understand something..,after i put my code in a div.php file,then should i delete the code from my index.html and replace it with "<?php include 'div.php'; ?>" or what?

Comment: Yes if that is were the code is. The "<?php include 'div.php'; ?>" will take its place.

Comment: So i've replaced the entire code above with "<?php include 'div.php'; ?>" and i've created the div.php and there i've wrote that code i deleted,but the wrapper containing everything is missing..

Comment: you will also have to add any css to the div.php file that your divs need to display properly/ also make sure you have correct path to the file.

Comment: well the code was displayed fine when it was in index.html, i just cut and paste it in the div.php,and when you say the corect path you mean on the "<?php include 'div.php'; ?>" right? then yes.The php file have div name.But it still dont appear.

Comment: when you open the div.php file it should look like how you want it to look on each of you pages. Meaning you need to include all css used for the divs inside the file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8FvWB/  here i post my entire code.I'm pretty sure i've wrote everything but it still dont appear

Comment: in that fiddle you have html in the javascript area

Comment: i wrote in js area the div.php because i couldnt find the php area,anyway i just wrote there to see the entire code.

Comment: Are you using images as your Backgrounds?

Comment: The only thing I do not see when i run the code is the images.

Comment: yes because i'm not familiar with jsfiddle and i dont know where to upload the images,but thats not important.I only want to show you the code so that you can see if is something wrong

Comment: w3schools is an [unreliable source](http://www.w3fools.com/) and should be avoided.

Comment: @borodin so what site would you use? I posted this site just as a start for OP to learn some php. Is there a better one?

Comment: @Redstone: [hardcoder.com](http://www.hardcoder.com/scripting/php/include_files.php) is pretty good